# CMIS 1.1 - Create Document via Browser binding (Alfresco)

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I want to use the browser binding introduced by CMIS 1.1 on Alfresco 4.2.
I can find a document with a SQL92 query but I cannot create a new one:

```
POST http://localhost:8180/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser?succinct=true HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8180
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 496507
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

------WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmisaction"

createDocument
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="propertyId[0]"

cmis:objectTypeId
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="propertyValue[0]"

cmis:document
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="propertyId[1]"

cmis:name
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="propertyValue[1]"

mydoc.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="versioningState"

none
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVIchQ4xxZi4TwAe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����
```

RESPONSE:
{
exception: "runtime"
message: null
stacktrace: "org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.java:80) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at ...
}

It seems to be a NullPointerException. In the log file I see that getGUID() is the last call:

```
2014-04-14 11:49:28,701  ERROR [impl.browser.CmisBrowserBindingServlet] [http-apr-8180-exec-1] 
 org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy303.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.support.CmisServiceWrapper.createDocument(CmisServiceWrapper.java:719)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.browser.ObjectService$CreateDocument.serve(ObjectService.java:102)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.shared.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:88)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.browser.CmisBrowserBindingServlet.dispatch(CmisBrowserBindingServlet.java:352)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.browser.CmisBrowserBindingServlet.service(CmisBrowserBindingServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISServletDispatcher.execute(CMISServletDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISWebScript.execute(CMISWebScript.java:51)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:377)
    at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:45)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:341)
    at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.access$001(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:26)
    at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer$1.doWork(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:81)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsWork(TenantUtil.java:119)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsTenant(TenantUtil.java:88)
    at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.executeScript(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.TenantWebScriptServlet.service(TenantWebScriptServlet.java:74)
    at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiWebScriptServlet.service(PublicApiWebScriptServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISConnector.getGuid(CMISConnector.java:1139)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISConnector.constructObjectId(CMISConnector.java:1194)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISConnector.constructObjectId(CMISConnector.java:1181)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISNodeInfoImpl.<init>(CMISNodeInfoImpl.java:91)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISConnector.createNodeInfo(CMISConnector.java:1107)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.getOrCreateNodeInfo(AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.getOrCreateFolderInfo(AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.java:227)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.createDocument(AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.java:1073)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.PublicApiAlfrescoCmisService.createDocument(PublicApiAlfrescoCmisService.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor$1.execute(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor.invoke(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisStreamInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisStreamInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisServiceInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.java:50)
    ... 48 more
```

Does anyone try to create a document via alfresco browser binding?

Answer (score 2):

Use the apache CMIS workbench. You can also try the online version linked at [Alfresco](http://cmis.alfresco.com/opencmis/workbench.jnlp).

Us the following url to work with it:

```
<host>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser
```

Use the browser binding and create an object, capture the url & request send.

A nice browser binding blog is found [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/manningpubs/archive/2013/07/02/browser-binding-cmis-repository), which explains a bit more than the Alfresco docs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cmis workbench does not support CMIS 1.1 JSON binding. It only exposed cmis atom and webservices binding...

Comment: In fact, your blog link is very usefull but I think that I missed something.

Comment: eehum yes it does (maybe not the alfresco workbench, but you can download the latest version). I've got a browser binding button which supports the JSON binding. I'm not 100% sure if it's 1.1 but it's def JSON CMIS.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake!

In order to use the cmisaction "createDocument", you need to specified the refered folderId in the query string.
Like this:

```
http://localhost:8180/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser
?objectId=5f2a7593-7eef-410d-9805-659dff5d4603
```

In that case, the new document is created into this folder.